# Issues with Form Duplication in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that allows users to dynamically add forms by clicking a + icon. Everything is working properly, except, when I close the modal and reopen it, the input fields and buttons are duplicated.

For instance:
I open the modal, click the plus, and a new input appears. I close the modal and reopen it, and the inputs are gone. Great!

However, when I click the + icon after opening the modal again, two inputs are added instead of one. If I repeat the process (close the modal, reopen, and click plus) three inputs appear, then four, and so on until the page is refreshed.

The fields are being appended to a simple div and I can't see why the number of fields that are added increases incrementally every time I reopen the modal and hit the +. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var i = 1;

// When the user cicks the + icon, a new input and dropdown list will appear

$("#new_rule").click(function() {

//markup for the input form
var user = "<div class='users'><input type='text' name='name' placeholder='name' class='form-control input" + i + "' style='margin-top:5px;'></div>"

//Markup for the dropdown
var perm = "<div class='permissions'><div class='btn-group input" + i + "' style='padding-top:4px;'><button type='button' name='options' id='options' class='btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'><span id='selected" + i + "'><span id='text'>Read</span></span></button><div class='dropdown-menu'><a class='dropdown-item 'href='#'>Read</a><a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Write</a><a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Full Control</a><a class='dropdown-item remove' href='#'>Remove</a><div class='dropdown-divider'></div><a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Learn More</a></div></div>";

//Concat the markup and append it to the wrapper
var input = user + perm;
console.log(input);
// Append the markup to the wrapper
$(".wrapper").append(input);
// Update the dropdown to reflect what they selected
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function() {
  // $('#text').text($(this).text());
  $(this).parent().siblings('button').find('span').text($(this).text());
})
i++
//Show the save button when a new entry is initially added.
$("#save").show();
});


// Clear forms when the x is clicked
$(".close").click(function() {
  $("input[name='name']").remove();
  $("button[name='options']").remove();
  $(".users").remove();
  $(".permissions").remove();
  $("p.index").remove();
  $("p.value").remove();
  $("#save").hide();
});
```

Comment: try setting `html` instead of calling `append`, that should wipe out all the content and allow you to start fresh. Something like `$(".wrapper").html(input)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the `#new_rule` element is always on the page (even when the modal is closed) but you're reattaching the event handler every time you open the modal:

```
$("#new_rule").click(function() {
```

jQuery won't *replace* event handlers when you do that; it'll just add new ones. So you end up with several copies of the same function running.

Either add that function only once (and not at the time the modal opens) or be sure to remove the old copy before adding the new one.

Comment: You are exactly right. Adding $("#new_rule").off(); removed the event handler and resolved the issue. Thank you so much!